# Recursively replace placeholder substrings based on related row data

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, replace

I have this array:

```
$data = [
    ["id" => 1, "data" => "data 1"],
    ["id" => 2, "data" => "data <4>"],
    ["id" => 3, "data" => "data 3"],
    ["id" => 4, "data" => "<3>"]
];
```

I want to produce a new array. The resulting array should be:

```
[
    ["id" => 1, "data" => "data 1"],
    ["id" => 2, "data" => "data data 3"],
    ["id" => 3, "data" => "data 3"],
    ["id" => 4, "data" => "data 3"]
]
```

The idea is that each time there is `<number>` in the `data` attribute then this value should be replaced by the `data` attribute in the element which has the same `id`. In the example above, the last element is: `["id" => 4, "data" => "<3>"]`

So we replace `<3>` with `data 3` since it is what is stored in the `data` attribute of element with `id => 3`.

I have already created a function that works with the above array:

```
public function refProcess($data, &$newData, $i, &$tmpData){
    $dataLength = count($data);
    if($i>=$dataLength){
        return;
    }
    for(;$i<$dataLength;$i++){
        if(is_null($tmpData)){
            $tmpData = ['id'=> $data[$i]['id'], 'data'=>null];
        }

        if(strpos($data[$i]['data'],"[")!==false){

            $parsed = $this->getInbetweenStrings("<", ">", $data[$i]['data']);
            if(count($parsed)){

                foreach($parsed as $occurance){
                    foreach($data as $key => $dataValue){
                        if($dataValue['id']==$occurance){

                            if(strpos($dataValue['data'], "<")!==false){

                                $this->refProcess($data, $newData, $key, $tmpData);
                                $tmpData=null;
                            }
                            else{
                                
                                $tmpDataAtt = str_replace("<".$occurance.">", $dataValue['data'], $data[$i]['data']);
                                $tmpData['data'] = $tmpDataAtt;
                                $newData [] = $tmpData;
                                $tmpData = null;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $tmpData['data'] = $data[$i]['data'];
            $newData [] = $tmpData;
            $tmpData = null;
        }
    }//foreach
}
```

//returns an array contains strings existing between $start and $end. Multiple occurance
public function getInbetweenStrings($start, $end, $str){
$matches = array();
$regex = "/$start([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$end/";
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
return $matches[1];
}

It works fine until I add another element to the array:

```
$data = [
    ["id" => 1, "data" => "data 1"],
    ["id" => 2, "data" => "data <4>"],
    ["id" => 3, "data" => "data 3"],
    ["id" => 4, "data" => "<3>"]
    ["id" => 5, "data" => "<2>"]
];
```

Element with `id:5` the function goes into an endless loop. What am I missing?

The code can be tested at https://onlinephp.io/c/0da5d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont really do any recursive stuff, is a quit flat array structure you have.

UPDATE: This was wrong, keep it just for the related comments:

```
<?php

$data = [
    ["id" => 1, "data" => "data 1",],
    ["id" => 2, "data" => "data <4>",],
    ["id" => 3, "data" => "data 3",],
    ["id" => 4, "data" => "<3>",],
    ["id" => 5, "data" => "<2>",]
];
foreach ($data as &$set) {
    $set['data'] = preg_replace_callback('#.*(\d+).*#', function ($m) {
         return 'data ' . $m[1];
    },$set['data']);
}
print_r($data);
```

UPDATE:
Here is now a working solution.

```
<?php

$data = [
    ["id" => 1, "data" => "data 1",],
    ["id" => 2, "data" => "data <4>",],
    ["id" => 3, "data" => "data 3",],
    ["id" => 4, "data" => "<3>",],
    ["id" => 5, "data" => "<2>",],
    ["id" => 6, "data" => "data <7>",],#loop to 7
    ["id" => 7, "data" => "<6>",],#loop to 6
    ["id" => 8, "data" => "<0>",],#dead link
    ["id" => 9, "data" => "<10>",],#multi level loop
    ["id" => 10, "data" => "data <11>",],#multi level loop
    ["id" => 11, "data" => "<9>",],#multi level loop
];
#just for testing: order can be ignored
shuffle($data);
#step 1 make keys easy to access
$prepared = [];
$tmp=[];
foreach ($data as $set) {
    $prepared[$set['id']] = $set['data'];
    $tmp[$set['id']] = $set;
}
$data=$tmp;
#setp 2 replace values
$final = [];
do {
    foreach ($data as $k => &$set) {
        $set['data'] = preg_replace_callback('#(.*)<(\d+)>#', function ($m) use ($prepared,$k) {
            #check for dead links
            if(!isset($prepared[$m[2]])){
                return $m[1]." ?{$m[2]}?";
            }
            #check for loop refer
            if(strpos($prepared[$m[2]],"<".$k.">")!==false){
                return $m[1]." §{$m[2]}§";
            }
            return $m[1].$prepared[$m[2]];
        }, $set['data']);
    
        if (strpos($set['data'], '>') === false) {
            $final[$k] = $set;
            unset($data[$k]);
        }
        
    }
 
} while (count($data));
ksort($final);
print_r($final);
```

UPDATED:

1. Now checks for dead links or loops and marks them.
2. Added more prepare code, so order is now ignorable

Comment: Doesn't work on initial dataset. The output should be 1-3-3-3. Your code produces 1-4-3-3. This should be recursive.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think you understood the requirements. Whenever there is `<number>` then this whole part should be replaced with the `data` from the element of `id:number` so for `data <4>` we have to go to element with `id:4` which has `data: <3>` so again we have to go to element with `id:3` which has `data:data 3` then this is the value that should replace `<4>` in element with `id:2`. I hope this is not too confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is too clumsy to begin with. I would rather suggest a much simpler approach.

---

- Index your array with `id` value as it's key with `array_column`. This way, we can access any index with `id` of a particular value in O(1) time. This also gives you an advantage for the value of the `id` to be anything and not necessarily being symmetric with your subarray index key.
- Capture the ID using regex. If there is a match, recurse again, else, our search ends here. Return it's `data` value to the parent call and you are done.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$data = array_column($data, null, 'id');

foreach($data as $id => $d){
  getLeafNodeValue($id, $data);  
}

function getLeafNodeValue($id, &$data){
  $matches = [];
  if(preg_match('/<(\d+)>/', $data[$id]['data'], $matches) === 1){
    $data[$id]['data'] = preg_replace('/<(\d+)>/', getLeafNodeValue($matches[1], $data), $data[$id]['data']);
  }
  return $data[$id]['data'];
}

print_r($data);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yrwxwrag)

Comment: Formally this doesn't work strictly as desired. The id:2 entry gotta have the "data data 3" value coz of its template "data <4>".

Comment: @Jared Did you see the expected output in OP?

Comment: Yep, i believe there's a mistake in the input data or either desired output. Need to ask @xoxaro

Comment: @Jared That's true. The output is not exactly correct in my post.

Comment: @nice_dev I edited the output above to be the correct one.

Comment: @xoxaro That changes everything although my answer needs simple modifications. Will update you soon.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I think Foobar is sufficient but if you would like to try i'd be happy to see another way and learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is way too complicated, there's an easier approach. Note, I reindex the initial data to the key:id -> value:array, to avoid all those loops for finding the entry for required id.

```php
<?php
$data = [
    [
        "id"=>1,
        "data"=>"data 1",
    ],
    [
        "id"=>2,
        "data"=>"data <4>",
    ],
    [
        "id"=>3,
        "data"=>"data 3",
    ],
    [
        "id"=>4,
        "data"=>"<3>",
    ],
    [
        "id"=>5,
        "data"=>"<2>",
    ]
];

function getValue( $arr, $id ){

    // Required data contains placeholder, going deeper
    if( preg_match("/<\d+>/", $arr[$id]['data']) ){
        return preg_replace_callback("/<(?<source_id>\d+)>/", function( $matches ) use ($arr) {

            return getValue( $arr, $matches['source_id'] );

        }, $arr[$id]['data'] );
    }

    // Return raw value as-is
    return $arr[$id]['data'];
}


// Reindexing to get convinient access
$indexed_data = [];
foreach( $data as $entry )
    $indexed_data[ $entry['id'] ] = $entry;

// Resolving through recursive getValue function
foreach( $indexed_data as $id => &$entry )
    $entry['data'] = getValue( $indexed_data, $id );

// Output in desired format
print_r( array_values( $indexed_data ) );
```

If there may be two entries with the same id, this approach not gonna work.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you please explain `getValue` a bit. Idon't understand how it works. Also if we want to make `<` and `>` dynamic, so that they take another placeholder such as `(` and `)` is it possible?

Comment: It's all about regexps. To change delimiters to `()` just replace `<>` inside regexps to `\(\)` respectively. Dynamic delimiters might be used aswel. Just construct regexp string with delimiters you want (passing em as another getValue arg probably).
So getValue is replacing a `<>` placeholder with a value that is beeing returned by recursive call to itself with id extracted from that placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidy recursive snippet that will modify your array by reference.

Loop over the array (I am choosing to use array de-structuring syntax to declare individual row variables.

If the needle is null or matches the row id, attempt the recursive replacement.

If the needle matches a row's id, return the value to the parent level, so that eventually the top level array is affected.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IAp1r))

```
function recurse(&$array, $needle = null) {
    foreach ($array as ['id' => $id, 'data' => &$data]) {
        if (($needle ?? $id) === $id) {
            $data = preg_replace_callback(
                '/<(\d+)>/',
                fn($m) => recurse($array, (int) $m[1]),
                $data
            );
        }
        if ($needle === $id) {
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
recurse($array);
var_export($array);
```

Comment: Thank you. Neat code. how could we avoid deadlocks?